# How to unittest a method that is called in the constructor of the tested class with phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a class `Version` and I want to unittest the `isValidVersionString()` method.

```
use InvalidArgumentException;

class Version
{
    /**
     * dot separated representation of the version
     * @var string
     */
    protected $versionString;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->setVersionString($value);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVersionString(): string
    {
        return $this->versionString;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $versionString
     *
     * @return Version
     */
    public function setVersionString(string $versionString)
    {
        if(!$this->isValidVersionString($versionString)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }
        $this->versionString = $versionString;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * valid format is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, with xxx not larger than 255
     * @param string $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValidVersionString(string $value): bool
    {
        //todo: implementation
    }
}
```

How can I build this unittest? Because this method is also called via the constructor.

Comment: what about to define the method `isValidVersionString`  as static and simple test as is?  PS: This comment because the method **is** static by design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a partial mock of the class:

```
class VersionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function itShouldTest()
    {
        /** @var Version|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $mock */
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Version::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['setVersionString','getVersionString'])
            ->getMock();

        $this->assertTrue($mock->isValidVersionString('a-string'));
    }

}
```

IMHO you can simply define the method `isValidVersionString` as `static` and simply test as is.